# How to use local xsd for EhCache with Spring

Tags: spring, ehcache

We are facing one issue about EhCache and Spring, when we point XSD file in ehcache.xml to  http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd, everything is ok, our application can startup correct.
    But our server can't access external website, so we changed XSD location to local as below, but the application can't startup with following exception (already copy ehcache.xsd to classes folder, same as ehcache.xml).
    I have googled many solution, but it still can't be fixed. I need your help about this. Thank you very much.

Spring: 3.1.0
EhCache: 2.4.2
Server: Tomcat 6.0
Java  :  1.6

Config:

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd"
    updateCheck="false" monitoring="autodetect" dynamicConfig="true">
```

Exception:

```
2012-11-07 16:54:42,003 WARN [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] - <Ignored XML validation warning>
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'ehcache.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.warning(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:96)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:380)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:318)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.findSchemaGrammar(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2440)
    ... more
2012-11-07 16:54:42,007 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] - <Context initialization failed>
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 3 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/ehcache.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'ehcache'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    ... more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'ehcache'.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:131)

    ...  more
```

Comment: http://www.ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd

Answer (score 14):

Download [ehcache.xsd](http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd), put it to the same folder where is your config xml file.
modify the xml head like below, notice the **classpath** prefix:

```
<ehcache
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="classpath:ehcache.xsd">
```

This will work in the development and production environment.

Comment: this even work without `classpath:` prefix, if in same directory. thnks

Answer (score 7):

usually I set `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd"`, But this can't work in a offline environment.

Answer (score 1):

My Workaround is add this xsd file to absolute path, such as: c:/ehcache.xsd and point to this location in ehcache.xml.
Hope this will help someone who facing the same issue.

Still looking forward to find out other solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my case just downloading the file from http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd into `src/main/resources` solves the problem

```
cd src/main/resources
wget http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd
```