# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown protocol: classpath

Tags: java, apache-felix

When i try to configure ehcache.xsd in ehcache.xml with the below code snippet

`<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="classpath:ehcache.xsd" updateCheck="false">`

I get this exception when i try to start the server.

```
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: Unknown protocol: classpath
```

ehcache.xml is placed in my blueprint folder.

Is classpath not recognized by osgi bundles?

Comment: xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation must be an url.

Comment: try with file:///<drive>|/<path> instead of classpath:

Comment: I would prefer the path to be relative, if i just mention 'xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd"' without classpath then it tries to take the xsd from eclipse folder. Hence i was looking for a better way of achieving it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18671825/2231632  apparently, classpath is recognized. Else, if you're running in a web app, you can make it accessible via a http URL.

Comment: Hi @Prabugp, The mentioned link does not specify if its related to osgi. I do not want to specify it as a link. Hence trying with this approach.